# Why > sometimes move 4 whitespaces sometimes 3 whitespaces in my vim?

Tags: movement

Here is part of my vim setting:

```
set tabstop=4
set sts=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

When I edit a file in `/mtp/test`, type `print('ok')` in the first line, and type `1>` in ex mode, I get the normal result, character `p` is in the 5th column. `>` moves the whole line to the right by 4 whitespaces.

[image]
Now I edit a file in another directory `/home/debian/mydoc/source/shell/`,

```
sudo -E vim  /home/debian/mydoc/source/shell/test.py
print("ok")
```

When I type `1>` in ex mode, I get the strange output:
[image]

Character `p` is in the 4 column. `>` moves the whole line to the right by 3 whitespaces!

It shocks me!
I find that for all file which ended with `.rst` the value `shiftwidth` is `3`, how to search which plugin set it with `3`?

Comment: Have you checked that the value of your settings is the same for both files? I see that you edit a file without filetype and one python file maybe a plugin changes the values (you can check with `:set shiftwidth?` Also your second command uses `sudo -E`, just to be sure the problem doesn't come from there have you reproduced the issue without `sudo`?

Comment: It is no difference with or without sudo,i find that for all file which ended with .rst the value shiftwidth is 3,how to search which plugin set it with 3?

Comment: `:verbose set shiftwidth` should give you the answer you're looking for

Comment: Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/rst.vim line 34

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As debugged in the comments:

The ftplugin for `rst` files sets `shiftwidth` to a value you don't like, so you will need to override it. To do so create the following file:

```
$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/rst.vim
```

And in it add the following line:

```
set shiftwidth=4
```

And you should be good to go. Have a read at [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin) if you are not familiar with ftplugins.