# Loading C file overwrites indentation settings in .vimrc

Tags: indentation, filetype-c

When I open a C file in vim, it seems to think I want 8 spaces worth of indentation, even though I specify my indentation preferences in `.vimrc` with the below:

```
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
```

I also have:

```
filetype indent plugin on
```

The only fix I've come across so far is `:set sw=4` in the buffer of the C file. I don't know why this works because I'm already setting that value in the `.vimrc`, so I can only guess that it's getting overwritten when the file-specific indentation settings are loaded. Unfortunately, deleting the `filetype ...` line from my `.vimrc` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You can check the current value and where they were last set with `:verbose set ts sts sw` (`ts` being the short name for `tabstop`, `sts` for `softtabstop`, and `sw` for `shiftwidth`).

Comment: To me that looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29243/1841). There are a lot of chances that `:verbose set shiftwidth` will point a ftplugin that you'll want to override

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments letting me know about `:verbose`. It turns out there was another vim config file on the remote machine I'm using hidden in `/etc/`. Unfortunately it's read only, and it seems like it has priority when it comes to  this line:

```
autocmd FileType c setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab
```

Comment: You can probably get around it with `vim -u ~/.vim/vimrc`, but that's annoying.